# How can I learn array database Rasdaman easily?

Tags: c++, sql, arrays, database, bigdata

I'm working at VietNam - HaNoi National University and I've a research at BigData satellite raster image by array database.

A solution is using Rasdaman database which has been developed many years. I've installed this server successfully, try to make some query with this by using this guide from rasdaman.org. Everything should be ok but I've known that this has a GUI tool name Rview.

I can't search Rview from any where (may be it's too old), I need some GUI tool because I some time don't really know what is error in my query and I need some tool that can show me the result (2D, 3D) with interractive viewer.

Please tell me how can I get a tool that can have GUI as MS SQL Database management tool, Phpmyadmin,...

Answer (score 1):

Rview (recently renamed to rasdaview actually, to avoid clashing with vim) is a GUI client for rasdaman that allows to send queries and has some cool visualization capabilities for 1D to 3D data.

The problem with rasdaview is that it has been last compiled 10+ years ago against wxWidgets 1.6x and the [code](http://rasdaman.org/browser/applications/rview%20code) is so outdated and incompatible with recent wxWidgets that it's not possible to compile it anymore without significant rewriting.

So rasdaman comes with this rview binary, which amazingly still works on most systems today. However, since it's not possible to compile it, it's a bit tricky to get it running. These [guidelines](http://rasdaman.org/wiki/Install#rview) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a website where you can execute your DDL or DML statements?

If yes then try [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: thanks Neels for your quickly answer but now I want to know that "If" has some tools that can parse "rasql query" and give me some errors which I can know. Not error 300, 500, 701,...and nothing explain. This is really tired and I also not how to run file .ql from rasql shell input parameter. Could you know that?